# Kubernetes : two containers in same pod cannot connect through localhost

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect two containers using localhost within the Kubernetes pod. But I'm not able to do so

#### kubernetes.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: db
      service: db-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type: db
        service: db-service
        db: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: db
        image: mysql:8.0
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: "qwertyuiop"
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: "iiitbspring"
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: "iiitbspring"
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: "foody"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306


---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apiserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      type: server-microservice
      service: api-server-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type: server-microservice
        service: api-server-service
        framework: spring-boot
        language: java
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: #################
      - name: api-server
        image: #################
        env:
        - name: username
          value: "iiitbspring"
        - name: password
          value: "iiitbspring"
        - name: DB_URL
          value: "jdbc:mysql://db-service:3306?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC"
        # ports:
        # - containerPort: 80
        # - containerPort: 8686
        # livenessProbe:
        #   httpGet:
        #     path: /api/foods
        #     port: 8686
        # readinessProbe:
        #   httpGet:
        #     path: /actuator/health
        #     port: 8686
        #   periodSeconds: 1

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    type: db
    service: db-service

---


apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api-server
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  # - name: api
  #   port: 8686
  #   targetPort: 8686
  - name: http
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    type: server-microservice
    service: api-server-service
```

I can easily do the same using docker compose :

```
version: "3.3"
services: 
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    networks:
      - database
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=qwertyuiop
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=foody
      - MYSQL_USER=iiitbspring
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=iiitbspring
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10

  server:
    build: ./backend/
    image: #################
    depends_on: 
      - db
    networks: 
      - database
      - server
    environment: 
      - username=iiitbspring
      - password=iiitbspring
      - DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:3306?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    expose:
      - "8686"
    ports:
      - "8686:8686"
    # healthcheck:
    #   test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:4444/actuator/health || exit 1"]
    #   timeout: 10s
    #   retries: 6

  app:
    build: ./foodyFrontEnd/
    image: #################
    networks: 
      - server
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    depends_on: 
      - server

volumes:
  db-data:

networks:
  database:
    driver: bridge
  server:
```

A bit about both the containers that I want to run: A backend container which is running springboot application at port 8686, other is an frontend container running angular using nginx on port 80.

The error I'm getting :
on visiting the URL : http://remote-url:3000/ I'm having my angular page but on the console I can see the error : GET http://localhost:8686/api/foods net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, where my webapp was trying to establish the connection to backend.

I tried curl inside the container but I cannot run it due to alpine.

Comment: It sounds like something in your application is sending the `localhost` URL out to the browser, which is then trying to connect to that port on the desktop system.  What generates that `.../api/foods` URL?  Why not run "app" and "api-server" in separate Deployments?

Comment: Well I also wanted to do that but, I don't don't know how do I send the URL to angular dynamically. I'm new to angular.

Comment: In my angular application I have created an constant with value http://localhost/ and in the entire application I am using this variable in http get as : http.get(http://localhost:8686/api/foods). subscribe ().

Comment: Hi there. Angular does not run on the server. Angular runs on the client in the browser. When the browser runs the angular app and calls locahost:xxx its actually hitting the clients computer

Answer (score 1):

As @David Maze said:

> The problem is that angular is running at client side, so when I was
> sending request to localhost then this is trying to connect to port on
> the desktop system.

Thanks @David Maze I just missed this point.

Comment: That's what I figured; how did you resolve this though? Did you have to deploy them into separate pods and somehow map the DNS/IP name instead?